Inductor as an antenna circuit
I'm looking on that circuit: https://github.com/LOM-instruments/Elektrosluch-DIY

I try to understand what is the use of the inductor? I understands it used as kind of antenna(?) to pick up small ekectromagnetic interference and then passed into an opamp to amplify it with a gain of 390 ?
what is happening in the inductor that makes it to pickup electromagnetic noises(?)
thanks for any explanations!

It depends on the inductor.
A shielded inductor, or a wound toroid ring inductor, won't pick up anything at all. They are designed not to couple externally at all.
An unshielded inductor, common in small values and physical packages, typically a coil of wire wound round a ferrite bar, will couple with external magnetic fields. A changing magnetic field will induce a voltage in the winding.
Any operating appliance such as a computer or phone will have changing currents flowing somewhere in it, which will create changing magnetic fields nearby. How strong these fields are next to the appliance will depend on how it has been designed. Most appliances will be designed to emit less than some threshhold magnetic field in order to meet Electromagnetic Compatibility regulations, so you may or may not be able to pick up anything significant.

this schematics is used for picking up "sounds" from electrical machines such as computer, phones etc. what is I try to understand is how is this magnetic field is appearing at the coil ?

@Omer Your schematic only indicates "22mH" inductor. How external magnetic fields couple into its structure is not given by your schematic symbol. As Neil has said, inductor construction makes a great deal of difference in this respect. You would want an inductor with a closed loop path that includes "air" for sensing external fields. A 22mH inductor likely includes some core material in the path too.

@Omer added final paragraph, which may help.

So the inductor is picking up changes in the magnetic field and those changes are transform into small changes in voltage that get amplify by the opamp? Do I get it right?

@Omer Yes, correct
